# Using Asp.Net Core Viewbag

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, menu, viewbag

Layout.cshtml

```
@{ 
    var menus = (IEnumerable<WebApplication.Models.TopMenu>)ViewBag.menus;
    
}
 
<div class="col-md-8">
    <!-- Menu Partial -->
    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/MainPage/TopMenu.cshtml", menus);
</div>
```

`MainPageController.cs`:

```cs
public IActionResult Mainpage()
{ 
    ViewBag.menus = db.TopMenu.Where(a => a.Active).OrderBy(a => a.Order);
    return View();
}
```

`TopMenu.cshtml`:

```
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
       
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication.Models.TopMenu>
<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu" >
    <li><a href="#">MainPage</a></li>
    @{ 
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>
                @if (item.ParentId == null && Model.Where(a => a.ParentId == item.Id).Any())
                {
                    <a href="/PageDetail/@item.Name-@item.Id">@item.Name</a>
                }
                else if (item.ParentId == null && Model.Where(a => a.ParentId != item.Id).Any())
                {
                        var link = "";
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Link)) { link = item.Link; }
                        else { link = "/PageDetail" + item.Name + "-" + item.Id; }
                        <a href="@link">@item.Name</a>

                }
            <ul>
    @foreach (var item1 in Model.Where(a => a.ParentId == item.Id))
    {
        <li><a style="text-transform:none;" href="/PageDetail/@item1.Name-@item1.Id" >@item.Name</a></li>

    }
            </ul>               
        </li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

I'm trying to show the top menu names from  using database .
Doesn't work and doesn't give an error.I tried to migrate with view bag and I am using ms sql.
What should i do to get the menu names?

THE OTHER WAY

MainPageController.cs

```cs
public IActionResult MainPage()
{        
    //     ViewBag.cars = db.Cars.OrderByDescending(a => a.date).Take(6);//view bag works for cars         
    var cars = db.Cars.OrderByDescending(a => a.date).Take(11);//it works this way too
            
    //ViewBag.menus = db.TopMenu.Where(a => a.Active).OrderBy(a => a.Order).ToList();        
        
    return View(cars);
}

public IActionResult Menu() {
    var menus = db.TopMenu.OrderByDescending(a => a.Active).OrderBy(a => a.Order);

    return View(menus);
}
```

note:
cars data works fine

`_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
     <!-- Menu Partial -->
     @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/MainPage/TopMenu.cshtml");
</div>
```

TopMenu.cshtml

THE OTHER WAY View COMPONENT

TopMenuViewComponent.cs

```
   namespace WebApplication.ViewComponents
{
    [ViewComponent(Name = "TopMenu")]
    public class TopMenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationContext _context;

        public TopMenuViewComponent(WebApplicationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {

            var menus = await _context.TopMenu.ToListAsync();
            return View("TopMenu", menus);
        }
      
    }
}
```

Shared/Components/TopMenu/TopMenu.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@model IEnumerable<WebApplication.Models.TopMenu>
<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
    <li><a href="#">MainPage</a></li>
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>
                @if (item.ParentId == null && Model.Where(a => a.ParentId == item.Id).Any())
                {
                    <a href="/PageDetail/@item.Name-@item.Id">@item.Name</a>
                }
                else if (item.ParentId == null && Model.Where(a => a.ParentId != item.Id).Any())
                {
                    var link = "";
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Link)) { link = item.Link; }
                    else { link = "/PageDetail" + item.Name + "-" + item.Id; }
                    <a href="@link">@item.Name</a>

                }
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item1 in Model.Where(a => a.ParentId == item.Id))
                    {
                        <li><a style="text-transform:none;" href="/PageDetail/@item1.Name-@item1.Id">@item.Name</a></li>

                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
  <div class="col-md-8">
                        <!-- Menu Partial -->
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync("TopMenu")
                    </div>
```

first parent id must be null-->>SOLUTION
[image]

Comment: Bind the DB request to a List so that the server makes the EF call by adding `ViewBag.menus = db.TopMenu.Where(a => a.Active).OrderBy(a => a.Order).ToLIst()` then in your View read the list `var menus = (List<WebApplication.Models.TopMenu>)ViewBag.menus;` also consider switching to [ViewData](https://tech-related.com/p/5ujQq9VcH7)

Comment: I wouldn't use the viewbag for this. Pass the result of the query to the view as an argument and use a model (of type ienumerable<your type>) in the razor view,  like topmenu is doing.  Viewbag is just a nasty blob

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. I changed it but it didn't work.                      
 ViewBag.menus = db.TopMenu.Where(a => a.Active).OrderBy(a => a.Order).ToLIst()

Comment: MainPageController.cs                                                                                                                                                                                                                           public IActionResult MainPage()
        {
 
           var cars = db.Cars.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).Take(11);


           return View(cars);
        }




        public IActionResult Menu()
        {
      var menus= db.Menus.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).Take(11);
            return View(menus);


        }

Comment: I tried this way without using viewbag @JHBonarius

Answer (score 2):

1_create _ViewImports.cshtml in Views folder
write this line

```
@addTagHelper *,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

2_use tagHelper in Layout.cshtml

```
@{
      var menus = (IEnumerable<WebApplication.Models.TopMenu>)ViewBag.menus; 
    }

  <div class="col-md-8">
         <!-- Menu Partial -->
         <partial name="TopMenu.cshtml" model="@menus" />  
  </div>
```

other

```
<partial name="~/Views/MainPage/TopMenu.cshtml" model="@menus" />
```

Comment: What will this solve? Plus you lose the async.

Comment: I did it all. it still didn't .Thanks a lot for your comments.@h.abdizadeh

Comment: I will try it without using viewbag. i will update the question

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you forgot to add data in a html tag.

```
<a style="text-transform:none;" href="/PageDetail/@item1.Name-@item1.Id" >@item.Title</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.
I changed it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as your,  rendering a partial view in the layout, if the partial view has a model, in this case, we can use `ViewBag` to pass the model . But we need to rewrite `ViewBag` in the corresponding action if we use the Layout page in each page.

**Option 1:**

In controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
           var topMenu = new List<TopMenu>()
         {
        new TopMenu { Name = "Khushbu",Id= 1,Link = "Link1", ParentId = 1 },
        new TopMenu { Name = "Mohan", Id = 2 ,Link = "Link2", ParentId = 2},
        new TopMenu { Name = "John", Id = 3 ,Link = "Link3", ParentId = 3},
        new TopMenu { Name = "Martin", Id= 4,Link = "Link4", ParentId = 4},
        new TopMenu { Name = "Due", Id= 5,Link = "Link5", ParentId = 5 }
        };   // you also can get menus from database
            
            ViewBag.menus = topMenu;
            return View();
        }
public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            var topMenu = new List<TopMenu>()
         {
        new TopMenu { Name = "Khushbu",Id= 1,Link = "Link1", ParentId = 1 },
        new TopMenu { Name = "Mohan", Id = 2 ,Link = "Link2", ParentId = 2},
        new TopMenu { Name = "John", Id = 3 ,Link = "Link3", ParentId = 3},
        new TopMenu { Name = "Martin", Id= 4,Link = "Link4", ParentId = 4},
        new TopMenu { Name = "Due", Id= 5,Link = "Link5", ParentId = 5 }
        };
            ViewBag.menus = topMenu;
            return View();
        }
```

My TopMenu.cshtml is in shared folder, in layout add this :

```
 @{
        var menus = (IEnumerable<TopMenu>)ViewBag.menus;

    }
     <div class="col-md-8">
 <!-- Menü Partial -->
   @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/TopMenu.cshtml",menus);
```

result:

[image]

So, in this case, I prefer to use `ViewComponent`. Read [ViewComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.

**Option2:**

1.Create new folder named ViewComponents. In this folder, create new class named TopMenuViewComponent.cs as below:

```
   [ViewComponent(Name = "TopMenu")]
    public class TopMenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            List<TopMenu> menus = new List<TopMenu>()       {
        new TopMenu { Name = "Khushbu",Id= 1,Link = "Link1", ParentId = 1 },
        new TopMenu { Name = "Mohan", Id = 2 ,Link = "Link2", ParentId = 2},
        new TopMenu { Name = "John", Id = 3 ,Link = "Link3", ParentId = 3},
        new TopMenu { Name = "Martin", Id= 4,Link = "Link4", ParentId = 4},
        new TopMenu { Name = "Due", Id= 5,Link = "Link5", ParentId = 5 }
        };// you can also get from database
            return View("TopMenu", menus);
        }
    }
```

2.In Views folder, create new folders with path Views\Shared\Components\TopMenu. In TopMenu folder, add TopMenu.cshtml

3.In layout, add below code

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("TopMenu")
```

Result:

[image]

**Update**

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "TopMenu")]
    public class TopMenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ViewComponentMVCContext _context;

        public TopMenuViewComponent(ViewComponentMVCContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            
            var menus = await _context.TopMenu.ToListAsync();
            return View("TopMenu", menus);
        }
```

Comment: I created tables in ms sql for the data. How can I send the data in the table to the page with your method?without using a list.

Comment: Please check my update.@OceanWaves

Comment: var topMenu = await db.TopMenu.ToListAsync();

Comment: I checked the table and it works now thanks a lot for your help.@Qing Guo